# How to create dropdown button have a check icon on the left option list and pass value on text box

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please give me advise the framework using to create dropdown button like as:
[image]

Comment: Hi @pham, Are you want it custom feature or need to use jquery plugin?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It has been given only image to users to implement design. No code what he tried nothing, it seems he is asking to do his homework

Comment: @UmeshSehta: jquery or angularjs, you think which is the best.

Comment: @eirenaios: I only want some advises from everybody to using which is the best structure,script to implement it...And I don't know what 's name of the template have a check icon on left dropdown list.

Comment: @Pham,  I have not much knowledge about angular.js , i can help you with the  jquery.

Comment: @UmeshSehta: Thank you, Umesh. I have a issue: how to show check icon on the left vaue is seleted on dopdown list. Please you help me

Comment: @Pham, can you customized the dropdown. Bcoz you can add icon on the left by two ways.
1) Using plugin
2) Use of unordered list instead of dropdown.

Comment: @UmeshSehta: please help me review it, how to add check icon on the left value on dropdown when the value is cliked.. http://jsfiddle.net/BqKNV/413/

Comment: OK @PhạmQuốcBảo , i am checking

Answer (score 3):

Try this one,
[image: Check Mark inside dropdown]

You can change css as per your needs.

```
HTML CODE:

<div class="dropdown btn-group">
  <button class="btn btn btn-mini btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">

     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
  </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="demolist">
      <li class="dropdown-header">Search in:</li>
      <li><a href="#"><div class="user-check"></div>HTML</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><div class="user-check"></div>CSS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><div class="user-check"></div>JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
```

```
JQUERY CODE:

$('#demolist li a').on('click', function(){
    $('.user-click').removeClass('user-click');
    $(this).find('.user-check').addClass('user-click');
    $('#usr').val($(this).text());
});
```

---

```
CSS :

.user-check{
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #D3DAD9;
    border-radius: 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0px 6px 0px 0px;
    outline: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    transition: background-color 200ms ease 0s,border-color 200ms ease 0s;
    width: 16px;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
}

.user-click:before {
  bottom: 10px;
    content: "\2713";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    right: 0px;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    transition: all 1s ease-out 0s;
    width: 14px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #c1c1c1;
}
```

Comment: HI, @PhạmQuốcBảo , please check this answer.

Comment: @UmeshSehta: Thank you, Umesh. You are very kind.

Comment: Thank You @PhạmQuốcBảo, Happy to help you.

Comment: @PhạmQuốcBảo Let me know if you have any other need with this answer.